# after_create with multiple methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am trying to call two methods on an after create, but putting them into an array doesn't work... i can't find anything in the rails docs or google... anyone with experience?

```
after_create [:do_this, :do_that]
```

does not work

Comment: i normally write it without array notation and never had a problem with this. Maybe you can try that...
`after_create :do_this, :and_then_this`

Comment: well, i knew it had to be simple... but i didn't try the simplest thing. Post that and i'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No need to surround the methods in array. Simply use:

`after_create :do_this, :and_then_this`

**Bonus Information**:
If a `before_*` callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an `after_*` callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

Comment: To add in bonus information: In Rails 5, if any before_callback returns false then callback chain is not halted. To explicitly halt the callback chain, we need to use throw(:abort).

Comment: Do you mean, if `do_this` returns `false`, the method `and_then_this` won't be called? Because I tried it and it kept working. Using rails `5.0.0.1`.

Comment: Is there a way to send in arguments to them when keeping em on the same row like in a controller: `only: new` 
Would that be like `after_create :do_this, only: new, :and_then_this`

Answer (score 3):

You can also call a single method and orchestrate the order right on the method.

```
after_create :process


def process
  do_this
  do_that
  then_this
end
```

I personally prefer this approach. No hidden magic.

Comment: This approach works especially well when "after create" you need to update multiple properties on a database record. Instead of having multiple methods sequentially writing to the database with `update()` you can combined them into one `update()`.

Answer (score 2):

Why putting the two callback methods into an array?

after_create :do_this, :do_that

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, `after_action` seems to be inverted.

```rb
after_action :do_that_after, :do_that_before
```

Executed order currently is `do_that_before` then `do_that_after`

**Edit: using Rails 6.0.3.3**